# Have Django Read in a CSV Post from Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, django, csv, web-applications, raspberry-pi

I currently have a django web app which is deployed at: http://ltdiadams.pythonanywhere.com/, the home view consists of a bunch of graphs which are made from a csv (stored.csv) included in the project folder.

The structure is like so:

```
csvparser
    csvparser
        init.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
        wsgi.py

    dataset
        admin.py
        apps.py
        models.py
        * stored.csv *
        tests.py
        views.py
```

Here is a link to the github for the files: https://github.com/ltdiadams/Garden-Bot-3000.

The csv file 'stored.csv' is created using another python script on my Raspberry Pi which reads in values for moisture, light, temperature, etc. from sensors and outputs them into columns of a csv.

Now that I have the functioning web app which reads in from a csv I gave it with dummy values, I'm having trouble getting it to connect to the Pi. That is, how can I make it so that I can go to this website on my Pi, have the Pi output the csv file and have this website read and make the graphs from that csv rather than the one that's included in the django folder? The two csv files are exactly the same, just one has set values I used to get it up and running, and the other which is outputted on the Pi updates constantly as the sensors read in data, I would like for the web app to read in this data instead of my set values.

Is there a way to do this? Willing to give any clarifications as well!

Edit:

Now that I have the idea to have one user who can post a csv file and store it on the server with the pi getting access and using the requests library to log onto your web page and post the csv, can anyone walk me through this process? I've tried many different things like importing and exporting using models and even 'django-csvimport' but nothing worked for what I want to do. Would downloading django on my pi and then interfacing it that way be better?

Comment: I'm not really sure I got it. SO I just ask whether this would solve the issu.

If not, then try perhaps explain exactly who contains which data and who would like to get data from whom or tu push data to whom.

MY suggestion would be, that your djagno application has one dedicated user / password and that with this youser you can post a csv file and store it on your server.

Then the pi could use the requests library (with sessions) log onto your web page and post the csv

Comment: @gelonida is this easy to implement? That could fix it although I might not even need users if I could get the pi to post the csv? Essentially  what I want is for the pi to give the website the csv to read from rather than the one that it's included in the django project itself

Comment: @gelonida gave it some thought and it didn't occur to me that anyone could mess with the data without one user oops, that is exactly what I need I do believe thank you